# "Two-level" generic method argument inference with delegate

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Consider the following example:

```
class Test
{
    public void Fun<T>(Func<T, T> f)
    {
    }

    public string Fun2(string test)
    {
        return ""; 
    }

    public Test()
    {
        Fun<string>(Fun2);
    }
}
```

This compiles well.

I wonder why cannot I remove `<string>` generic argument? I get an error that it cannot be inferred from the usage.

I understand that such an inference might be challenging for the compiler, but nevertheless it seems possible.

I would like an explanation of this behaviour.

**Edit** answering Jon Hanna's answer:

Then why this works?

```
class Test
{
    public void Fun<T1, T2>(T1 a, Func<T1, T2> f)
    {
    }

    public string Fun2(int test)
    {
        return test.ToString(); 
    }

    public Test()
    {
        Fun(0, Fun2);
    }
}
```

Here I bind only one parameter with `T1 a`, but `T2` seems to be similarly difficult.

Comment: Re your edit, you have now supplied the compiler - via the `Fun(0, Fun2);` call. The compiler now knows it needs a method, from the `Fun2` method group, that has a `T1` type, in this case `int`. This narrows it down to one method and so it can infer which one to use.

Comment: But there is one Fun2 in the first place, so it does not really 'narrow' anything.

Comment: The C# compiler refuses to treat a method group containing only one method as a delegate. You have to provide it info to select a method from the group for it to bother to do so. It would be great if it looked at the group, realised there was just one method and selected it, but sadly that's not how it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can't infer the type, because the type isn't defined here.

`Fun2` is not a `Func<string, string>`, it is though something that can be assigned to `Func<string, string>`.

So if you use:

```
public Test()
{
  Func<string, string> del = Fun2;
  Fun(del);
}
```

Or:

```
public Test()
{
  Fun((Func<string, string>)Fun2);
}
```

Then you are explicitly creating a `Func<string, string>` from `Fun2`, and generic type-inference works accordingly.

Conversely, when you do:

```
public Test()
{
  Fun<string>(Fun2);
}
```

Then the set of overloads `Fun<string>` contains only one that accepts a `Func<string, string>` and the compiler can infer that you want to use `Fun2` as such.

But you're asking it to infer both the generic type based on the the type of the argument, and the type of the argument based on the generic type. That's a bigger ask than either of the types of inference it can do.

(It's worth considering that in .NET 1.0 not only were delegates not generic—so you would have had to define `delgate string MyDelegate(string test)`—but it was also necessary to create the object with a constructor `Fun(new MyDelegate(Fun2))`. The syntax has changed to make use of delegates easier in several ways, but the implicit use of `Fun2` as `Func<string, string>` is still a construction of a delegate object behinds the scenes).

> Then why this works?

```
class Test
{
    public void Fun<T1, T2>(T1 a, Func<T1, T2> f)
    {
    }

    public string Fun2(int test)
    {
        return test.ToString(); 
    }

    public Test()
    {
        Fun(0, Fun2);
    }
}
```

Because then it can infer, in order:

1. `T1` is `int`.
2. `Fun2` is being assigned to `Func<int, T2>` for some `T2`.
3. `Fun2` can be assigned to a `Func<int, T2>` if `T2` is `string`. Therefore `T2` is string.

In particular, the return type of `Func` can be inferred from a function once you have the argument types. This is just as well (and worth the effort on the part of the compiler) because it's important in Linq's `Select`. That brings up a related case, the fact that with just `x.Select(i => i.ToString())` we don't have enough information to know what the lambda gets cast to. Once we know whether the `x` is `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` we know we either have `Func<T, ?>` or `Expression<Func<T, ?>>` and the rest can be inferred from there.

It's also worth noting here, that deducing the return type is not subject to an ambiguity that deducing the other types are. Consider if we had both your `Fun2` (the one that takes a `string` and the one that takes an `int`) in the same class. This is valid C# overloading, but makes deduction of the type of `Func<T, string>` that `Fun2` can be cast to impossible; both are valid.

However, while .NET does allow overloading on return type, C# does not. So no valid C# program can be ambiguous on the return type of a `Func<T, TResult>` created from a method (or lambda) once the type of `T` is determined. That relative ease, combined with the great usefulness, makes it something the compiler is well to infer for us.

Comment: of course my edit was inspired by `Select`. Do you mean that it was simpler to implement return type inference in such case? To avoid problems with overloads? //Edit, that's what you have written, we had a race ;-) I'd love to see that in ECMA, would have to dig it up.

Comment: Just added a little on the fact that it is indeed simpler, because in all cases it's possible, while in some cases inferring parameter types is ambiguous. (And worse, if they did add support for the unambiguous cases, it's code that can be broken by reasonable additions that make it ambiguous again).

Comment: why it not infers it?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but I must say it leaves me dissatisfied a little. I didn't find anything justifying such behaviour in ECMA, although it's a difficult read, I could have missed something. It's disappointing. Bummer.

Answer (score 3):

You are wanting the compiler to infer `string` from `Fun2`, which is too much of an ask for the C# compiler. This is because it sees `Fun2` as a method group, not a delegate, when referenced in `Test`.

If you change the code to pass in the parameter needed by `Fun2` and invoke it from `Fun`, then the need goes away, as you now have a `string` parameter, allowing the type to be inferred:

```
class Test
{
    public void Fun<T>(Func<T, T> f, T x)
    {
        f(x);
    }

    public string Fun2(string test)
    {
        return test;
    }

    public Test()
    {
        Fun(Fun2, "");
    }
}
```

To answer your edited version of the question, by supplying the `T1` type you have now supplied the compiler - via the `Fun(0, Fun2);` call - extra information. It now knows it needs a method, from the `Fun2` method group, that has a `T1` parameter, in this case `int`. This narrows it down to one method and so it can infer which one to use.`